# Filtering SQL queries with php, and html select boxes

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am developing a website where by people can buy and sell new or used cars. I want to set up a simple filter using php and sql statements and also of course html select boxes (drop down options).  I have gotten all the other options to work with help and trust me it has been greatly appreciated. However i have been trying to get the "price filter" to work and been getting no where. Below is what my select box in html look like.

```
<select name="price" size="0">
<option value="100000">Under $100,000</option>
<option value="<?php echo " BETWEEN '100000' AND '250000' "?>">Between $100,000 and $250,000</option>
<option value=">250000<500000">Between $250,000 and $500,000</option>
<option value=">500000<750000">Between $500, 000 and $750,000</option>
<option value=">7500000">Over $750,000</option>
</select>
```

This is my $_POST statement for the price variable:

```
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
```

This is my sql statement:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM  `chjadb_vehicles` WHERE  `v_make` LIKE  '$make'AND `v_year` =  '$year'AND  `v_trans` LIKE  '$trans'AND  `condition` LIKE  '$cond' AND `b_style` LIKE '$b_style' AND `v_price` '$price'");
```

After which i have a basic loop that should print the results. Now from what i understand (correct or not), when the user selects a specific option from the drop down menu the value from "option value" is passed to the $_POST statement. After which it should replace $price with the actual text BETWEEN '100000' AND '250000', completing the query statement. So the final statement printed from the sql statement should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM  `chjadb_vehicles` WHERE  `v_make` LIKE  '$make'AND  `v_year` =  '$year'AND  `v_trans` LIKE  '$trans'AND  `condition` LIKE  '$cond' AND  `b_style` LIKE '$b_style' AND `v_price` BETWEEN '100000' AND '250000'"`
```

However i get this error:

BETWEEN \'100000\' AND \'250000\' You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' BETWEEN \'100000\' AND \'250000\' '' at line 8

Any ideas as to where i went wrong? Thanks

Regards,
D. Ruddock

Comment: Why won't you simply use `WHERE v_price >= 100000 AND v_price <= 250000`?

Comment: what is a "select boes"?

Comment: That should have been "Select Boxes"... Sorry about the typo correction made... When i use the statement you selected i get the following php error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''>= 100000 AND `v_price` <= 250000'' at line 8

Answer (score 1):

After the line:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `chjadb_vehicles` WHERE `v_make` L....
```

put:

```
echo "<br><br>".$sql."<br><br>";
```

temporarily, and look at the final SQL query in the browser when using the page. Find where the error is and then remove the "`echo`" statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new myself, but I don't think you need the quotes around the numbers in your BETWEEN statement.  I think you can take them out.  If I'm wrong I'm sure I'll be corrected, but that's my thought.

Comment: The quotations shouldn't be there but i automatically generated the PHP code with PHPMYADMIN and they included the quotations so i left them in

Answer (score 0):

Is the ` at the very end a typo? If it is not, that might be the problem.

Comment: yeah not sure how that got there